# Form problems with php. dynamically selected options and check box

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I'm pulling a list of client names out of one MySQL table to serve as a drop down selection. The data is to be stored on a separate table. I would like the option to come up as selected if there already is a client assigned to the field in the second table.

Also, my radio buttons are inputting their data into the wrong fields, any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

code below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $query  = "SELECT * ".
             "FROM studies ".
             "WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";

   $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
      list($id, $pagetitle, $title, $date, $copy, $outputs, $strategies, $client, $niche, $media, $thumbmedia, $newfieldtitle, $newfieldcontent) = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);



}

if(isset($_POST['update1']))
{
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $pagetitle = $_POST['pagetitle'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $copy = $_POST['copy'];
   $outputs = $_POST['outputs'];
   $strategies = $_POST['strategies'];
   $client = $_POST['client'];
   $niche = $_POST['niche'];
   $media = $_POST['media'];
   $thumbmedia = $_POST['thumbmedia'];
   $newfieldtitle = $_POST['newfieldtitle'];
   $newfieldcontent = $_POST['newfieldcontent'];

   if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
   {
      $pagetitle = addslashes($pagetitle);
      $title = addslashes($title);
      $date = addslashes($date);
      $copy = addslashes($copy);
      $outputs = addslashes($outputs);
      $strategies = addslashes($strategies);
      $client = addslashes($client);
      $niche = addslashes($niche);
      $media = addslashes($media);
      $thumbmedia = addslashes($thumbmedia);
      $newfieldtitle = addslashes($newfieldtitle);
      $newfieldcontent = addslashes($newfieldcontent);

   }

   // update the article in the database
   $query = "UPDATE studies
            SET pagetitle = '$pagetitle', title = '$title', date = '$date', copy = '$copy', outputs = '$outputs', strategies = '$strategies', client = '$client', niche = '$niche', media = '$media', thumbmedia = '$thumbmedia', newfieldtitle = '$newfieldtitle', newfieldcontent = '$newfieldcontent' ".
        "WHERE id = '$id'";
   mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());

   // then remove the cached file
   $cacheDir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/';

   $cacheFile = $cacheDir . '_' . $_GET['id'] . '.html';

   @unlink($cacheFile);

   // and remove the index.html too because the file list
   // is changed
   @unlink($cacheDir . 'index.html');

   echo "<b>Article '$title' updated</b>";

   // now we will display $title & content
   // so strip out any slashes
      $pagetitle   = stripslashes($pagetitle);
      $title   = stripslashes($title);
      $date   = stripslashes($date);
      $copy = stripslashes($copy);
      $outputs = stripslashes($outputs);
      $strategies = stripslashes($strategies);
      $client = stripslashes($client);
      $niche = stripslashes($niche);
      $media = stripslashes($media);
      $thumbmedia = stripslashes($thumbmedia);
      $newfieldtitle = stripslashes($newfieldtitle);
      $newfieldcontent = stripslashes($newfieldcontent);

}


?>


<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

<p class="subheadsmall">Browser Title</p>
<textarea cols="40" rows="1" class="box" name="pagetitle" id="editbox"><?php echo $pagetitle; ?></textarea>


<p class="subheadsmall">Story Title</p>
<textarea cols="40" rows="1" class="box" name="title" id="editbox"><?php echo $title; ?></textarea>

<p class="subheadsmall">Date</p>
<textarea cols="40" rows="1" class="box" name="date" id="editbox"><?php echo $date; ?></textarea>

<p class="subheadsmall">Story</p>
<textarea cols="80" rows="10" class="box" name="copy" id="editbox"><?php echo $copy; ?></textarea>

<p class="subheadsmall">Outputs</p>
<textarea cols="80" rows="10" class="box" name="outputs" id="editbox"><?php echo $outputs; ?></textarea>

<p class="subheadsmall">Strategies</p>


<p class="subheadsmall">Client</p>
<select type="text" name="client">
    <option value="empty">Select a Client...</option>
 <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients");
                if (!$result) {
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $clientlist = $row['name'];
    $clientname = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);


    if(isset($_POST['client'])){ 

    echo '<option value="' . $clientlist . '" selected="selected" >' . $clientname . '</option>' . '\n';
    }
    else{
    echo '<option value="' . $clientlist . '" >' . $clientname . '</option>' . '\n';
}
}


?>
</select>

<?php



echo '<p class="subheadsmall">Core Classification</p>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="niche" value="brand"' . ($niche == "brand" ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "") . ' >Brand</input>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="niche" value="marketing"' . ($niche == "marketing" ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "") . ' >Marketing</input>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="niche" value="communication"' . ($niche == "communication" ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "") . ' >Communication</input>';


?>

<p class="subheadsmall">Add New Strategy</p>
<textarea cols="40" rows="1" class="box" name="strategies" id="editbox"><?php echo $strategies; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I only have one thing to say... "?id=';delete from studies where true" oops...

Comment: This is not a reply to your question, but some thoughts that I came up with after having quickly read your code. Thought it might help.

You may want to consider using array_map() instead of applying the same function to your $_POST variables one by one. (e.g : array_map('addslashes', $_POST);)
Also you're first query use an unverified $_GET variable (and there's no need to put it between quotes). You might want to use intval() to make sure your ID is an integer.
Also, before printing a variable you might want to use the htmlentites().

Answer (score 1):

- Your `if(isset($_POST['client']))` condition doesn't reference `$row` at all, so it's going to either be true for all options or false for all options. I presume you want to compare `$_POST['client']` to `$clientlist` in that statement:

  ```
  if ($_POST['client'] == $clientlist)
  ```
- An `<input>` element does not contain content. Rather than `<input type="radio">Label</input>` it should just be `<input type="radio" /> Label` with the label after the input tag, not inside of it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, sorry to be a pain but how would I compare $_POST['client'] to $clientlist in that statement? 

Thanks for the <input> heads up, that was stupid!